# Developing webapi in Grails using jaxrs plugin Spring Security settings needed

Tags: grails, spring-security, jax-rs

I am developing the webapi using jaxrs plugin in a Grails project (existing) in which there is Spring Security configured which is not allowing me to access the api urls i.e `/api/**`

I am getting `You are not authorised to access this page` though I have logged in as Admin but I am not able to configure the access to this path with/without authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using spring security?

Authentication is generally handled a little differently when implementing a rest api. Check out the excellent [Spring Security REST Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-rest). There's some really nice documentation [here](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/) that explains the authentication lifecycle.